# Why is there no appearance of a newer Emacs after installing it on my Mac?

Tags: emacs

I just installed emacs on my mac from this website: https://emacsformacosx.com/

After copying it to my Applications, I opened emacs and did M-x emacs-version. My old version was still shown (22.1.1).

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: You are most likely just typing *emacs* from the terminal, which is going to give you the Emacs located here:  `/usr/bin/emacs`  This comes pre-installed with OSX.  If you saved the Emacs.app from the link you cite above into the `/Applications` folder, then your path to Emacs is `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs`  If you type that full path in the terminal, then you will be using the newest version.  You can fix your shortcut later so that you can type just **emacs** in the terminal and get the newest version.  You could also just double-click on Emacs.app and use the GUI version.

Comment: Thanks Lawlist, can you explain how to fix the shortcut? You can also post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Look at the bash `alias` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original poster is on a computer with an OS X operating system, which comes with an older version of Emacs that is pre-installed -- located at `/usr/bin/emacs`.  The newer pre-built version of Emacs that the original poster downloaded from https://emacsformacosx.com/ contains everything inside of a packaged folder called `Emacs.app`, which the OP stated was placed in the `/Applications` folder.  The path to the new Emacs executable is `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs`.  The OP has indicated a desire to be able to type the word **emacs** from the terminal and have the newer version of Emacs be activated, instead of the older version.  The comment by @greg-449 underneath the question above states that the OP should look at the bash `alias` command to properly configure which version of Emacs is activated when typing the word **emacs** from the terminal.

Unless there are specific reasons for using a non-GUI Emacs, the OP should consider using the GUI version (which can be launched from the terminal, or from the Dock or from Finder.app).